# Python - Position Argument missing

Tags: python

My Python code has the following class

```
class payment_calculations:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__interestdatecurrent = str()
        return None

    def paymentfixed(self, notional, datecouponstart, datecouponend, interestratecurrent, interestratefixed, datecurrent):
```

When I call it with

```
fixedpayment = payment_calculations.paymentfixed(interestnotional, datecoupon1, datecoupon2, c, interestratefixed, interestdatecurrent)
```

I see the following stack trace

```
 File "C:\Python34\mod_payment_calculation.py", line 83, in coupondatesfixed
    fixedpayment = payment_calculations.paymentfixed(interestnotional,datecoupon1,datecoupon2,c,interestratefixed,interestdatecurrent)
TypeError: paymentfixed() missing 1 required positional argument: 'datecurrent'
```

I have confirmed this works when calling from a test file. However when I run from within the module itself it fails. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create an *instance* of the class:

```
pc = payment_calculations()
fixedpayment = pc.paymentfixed(interestnotional, datecoupon1, datecoupon2, c, interestratefixed, interestdatecurrent)
```

otherwise you are calling an unbound function and the `self` argument is not going to be provided automatically. Instead, the `interestnotional` value goes to the `self` argument, the `datecoupon1` value to the `notational` argument, etc.

Comment: Doh! - I had created this module and class etc from a another file.